# Unable to start daemon process?

Tags: android

I'm getting following error,

> ```
> Error:"Unable to start the daemon process: could not reserve enough space for object heap.
> Please assign more memory to Gradle in the project's gradle.properties file.
> For example, the following line, in the gradle.properties file, sets the maximum Java heap size to 1,024 MB:
> <em>org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m</em>
> <a href="http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html">Read Gradle's configuration guide</a><br><a href="http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html">Read about Java's heap size</a>"
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to follow the instructions that are contained in the error message that you've posted?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

`Go to` `C:Users/username.gradle`   and **delete** that `username.gradle` file.

It may Help you.